# Networkx: how to optimize building a graph

Tags: python, optimization, networkx, graph-theory

I use `networkx` for building a graph which consists of keywords extracted from the texts. I tried 2 approaches and I noticed one strange thing.
The first approach is

```
def build_graph(all_nodes):
    G = nx.Graph()
    for nodes in all_nodes:
        for pair_of_nodes in itertools.combinations(set(nodes), 2):
            u, v = pair_of_nodes
            if G.has_edge(u, v):
                G[u][v]['weight'] += 1
            else:
                G.add_edge(u, v, weight=1)
    return G
```

and the second one is

```
def build_graph_2(all_nodes):
    nodes_weighted = Counter()
    for nodes in all_nodes:
        nodes_weighted.update(itertools.combinations(set(nodes), 2))
    return nx.Graph((x, y, {'weight': v}) for (x, y), v in nodes_weighted.items())
```

For testing I generated a random sample like `[[text_1_kw_1, text_1_kw_2, text_1_kw_3, ...], [text_2_kw_1, text_2_kw_2, ...], ...]`

```
texts = [[random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(500)]
texts = [list(map(str, text)) for text in texts]
```

Here the first approach gave

```
713 ms ± 27.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

And the second one

```
135 ms ± 9.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The second approach looks more attractive.

But length of a keyword usually is more than 10 chars. So here I make a new one test sample.

```
texts = [[random.randint(10000, 10000000000) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(500)]
texts = [list(map(str, text)) for text in texts]
```

However here we get the following result for the first approach

```
3.04 s ± 91.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

And for the second is

```
3.56 s ± 332 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The superiority of the second approach over the first decreased.
I don't fully understand why does it happen and how can I build a graph faster than using the first approach?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are addressing nodes by a text, which could be very long.  So every time you search for a node you have to compare a long text with every other long text - horribly slow.

Suggestion:  Use an integer index to address the nodes.  Initially build a map of indices (key) and the associated text (value).  Then build the graph using node indices.  Internally, work with node indices. Only look up the text for a node in the map when you are outputting human readable results.

Alternative:  Since your node texts are unique, use a set instead of a map.  Code it so the node index and the text index in the set are the same.  The code required will be simpler.

Comment: Thank you for suggesion. But did you mean that it's better to use integer nodes instead of the text nodes? And what about texts? Is it better to store it only in dict. What about nodes meta info?

Comment: Not instead of.  Index your nodes ( where you keep the text and any other info ).  Use the index to look up the node rather then the text.